# MySQL GROUP BY not working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count the number of softwares names using mysql
Here is my original that show everything

```
 Select dico_soft.FORMATTED,dico_soft.EXTRACTED,softwares.NAME
 From dico_soft
 INNER JOIN softwares
 ON dico_soft.EXTRACTED=softwares.NAME;
```

Where is what I added count and Group by sql

```
 Select dico_soft.FORMATTED,dico_soft.EXTRACTED,softwares.NAME,count(*)
 From dico_soft
 INNER JOIN softwares
 ON dico_soft.EXTRACTED=softwares.NAME;
 Group BY = softwares.NAME;
```

the result only give me 1 row which adds everything, the group by doesn't work

Comment: `GROUP BY` doesn't have an operator before it's identifier. Simply: `GROUP BY softwares.NAME`

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
Group BY softwares.NAME;
```

and not

```
Group BY = softwares.NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `"="` from `GROUP BY` of SQL query

```
Select dico_soft.FORMATTED,dico_soft.EXTRACTED,softwares.NAME,count(*)
 From dico_soft
 INNER JOIN softwares
 ON dico_soft.EXTRACTED=softwares.NAME;
 Group BY softwares.NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to execute the following query

```
 Select softwares.NAME,count(softwares.NAME) as Quantity
  From dico_soft
  INNER JOIN softwares
  ON dico_soft.EXTRACTED=softwares.NAME;
  Group BY softwares.NAME;
```

This will fetch software name and the quantity of each one

Answer (score 0):

You are trying set `GROUP BY` on `JOIN` table. You need grouping by `FROM` table. Also not need `= in GROUP BY`

```
 Select dico_soft.FORMATTED, 
        dico_soft.EXTRACTED, 
        softwares.NAME,
        count(dico_soft.EXTRACTED)
 From dico_soft
 INNER JOIN softwares ON dico_soft.EXTRACTED = softwares.NAME;
 Group BY dico_soft.EXTRACTED;
```